Dynamically inject variable into the data parameter of a curl statement
Given the --data parameter of a curl statement:
--data '{
    "collection": [
        "Library"
    ],
    "filter": "{'\''target.endpointUID'\'':{'\''$eq'\'': '\''ABC123'\''}}",
    "skip": 0,
    "limit": 16
}'

I'd like to replace ABC123 with the variable I want to use but I cannot figure out the correct way.

Don't create JSON with string concatenation. Use the jq utility. It allows you to set variables and then refer to them inside the JSON.

Why are you putting single quotes inside the JSON? JSON uses double quotes as string delimiters.

Have a look at Unable to pass variable to curl --data which also features two nested JSON encodings.

You want
data=$(
  jq -nc --arg uid "${your_variable}" '
    {
      "collection": ["Library"],
      "filter": "{\"target.endpointUID\":{\"$eq\": \"\($uid)\"}}",
      "skip": 0,
      "limit": 16
    }
  '
)

curl --data "$data" ...

or, a bit clearer
data=$(
  jq -nc --arg uid "${your_variable}" '
    {"target.endpointUID": {"$eq": $uid}} as $filter
    | {collection: ["Library"], filter: ($filter | tojson), skip: 0, limit: 16}
  '
)


You can use here-document (this assumes you don't have special characters like double quotes in $var):
var=ABC123
curl ... --data "$(cat << EOF
{
    "collection": [
        "Library"
    ],
    "filter": "{'target.endpointUID':{'\$eq': '$var'}}",
    "skip": 0,
    "limit": 16
}
EOF
)" ...


What's the point of the here-document?

The document contains two kinds of quotes. But of course jq is the right way to go.

@chepner here-document provides a much more readable version.

Readability doesn't matter much if $var contains a ``"`.
